# relationship between 2 fact tables in dimension usage - SSAS

Tags: ssas

I have 2 fact tables. One is being used as a dimension - Bridge table for multi valued Dimensions. The other is FactSales. What I am trying to achieve is to get a count of customers from sales table where they have a specific member property (comes from the other Fact Table). I thought making the relationship between the two is the way ahead.

I tried using the PersonID as the join in Dimension Usage tab, trying both regular and References (using DimPerson) but it didn't work. Does anyone know why this might be? Or what is the way around this?

Comment: Need more information.  What wrong results are you getting?  Is PersonID a PK in the bridge fact table, but a non-unique key in FactSales?

Comment: Agree with @SebTHU, without seeing the table structure, and the relationship you are trying to create, we can't even guess.

Comment: Table 1: FactSales, Table 2: FactRank (Used as a dim in the cube aswell), Table 3: DmPerson. Current relationships: DimPerson -> Fact Sales and DimPerson -> FactRank. I want to use the FactRand (dimension) as a search for FactSales. e.g. One column is like RankDesc (has 3 distinct values), I want to be able to use that and take for e.g. the profit from FactSales and for it to understand the link between (which is what I am after). Is that clearer?

Comment: What (wrong) results are you getting?  Are you using MDX queries or the browser?  (It's easier to read if you edit your question, rather than putting details in the comments).

Comment: Hi, I checked it again, and made a relationship between the two fact tables in the dimension usage tab using the primary key from FactRank joining on FactSales on FactRankID (fk). Its working fine now.